# Anchor view at the bottom - ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make a UI using `ConstraintLayout` according to following requirement.

Show `textView` below `recyclerView` if list has less item and not touching the bottom.
If list is long then `textView` must be anchored at the bottom, it should not move out of the screen.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Here is the sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lighterGrey"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/space_20"
        tools:context=".ui.settings.AddressFragment">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/address_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_profile_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_20"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_12"
                android:text="@string/address_profile_label"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/address_profile_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_8"
                android:background="@color/white"
         app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_profile_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_shipping_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_20"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_12"
                android:text="@string/address_shipping_label"
                android:textColor="@color/grey"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_profile_list" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/address_shipping_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_8"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_shipping_title" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address_add_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_20"
                android:padding="@dimen/space_12"
                android:text="@string/address_add_new_label"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address_shipping_list" />

            <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.CircularProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/address_progress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_150"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:indeterminateTint="@color/black"
                android:minWidth="@dimen/spinner_min"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/spinner_min"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Kindly let me know the corrections needed.

Comment: Kindly add your source code below.

Answer (score 1):

Set the *RecyclerView* up with `0dp` (*match_constraints*) for its width and height. When you do this set the start/top/end/bottom constraints to `parent`. `match_parent` should not be used for children of a *ConstraintLayout*.

Set the *RecyclerView* in a packed vertical chain with a vertical bias of `0.0`. This will move the *TextView* immediately below the *RecyclerView* and move the *RecyclerView* to the top of the layout.

For the *RecyclerView* set `app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"`. This will cause the *RecyclerView* to wrap its content when but not exceed the limits of its constraints. See [here](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/recent/constraintlayoutbeta5isnowavailable).

Here is a sample layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        tools:itemCount="50" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/recyclerView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

You can change the item count for the *RecyclerView* to see how it works.

Here is the layout with an item count of 50:

[image]

and with an item count of 25:

[image]